# How can I create a row for each quantity over 25 in a firebird select clause

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I am using a Firebird 2.5 database and I need to read a table, and based on the quantity, create additional records of data in my select statement. For example, If a quantity has a value of 10 I want to create one record with a quantity of 10. If the quantity has a value of 30, I need to create two records. One with a quantity of 25 and the other with a quantity of 5. I always want to divide the quantity by 25 and create records for each qty of 25 and one with the remainder of the quantity.

Here is the current sql. How would i modify it to create additional records?

```
SELECT 
trackinginfo.info AS ID,
IIF (pickitem.qty*(COALESCE(uomconversion.multiply,1)/COALESCE(uomconversion.factor,1)) > 4,        ROUND(pickitem.qty*  (COALESCE(uomconversion.multiply,1)/COALESCE(uomconversion.factor,1)),2),ROUND(pickitem.qty*(COALESCE(uomconversion.multiply,1)/COALESCE(uomconversion.factor,1)),4)) AS "Quantity Kg",
part.num||'-'||part.description as Part,
PICK.NUM AS "order"
FROM PICKITEM 
INNER JOIN PART ON PICKITEM.PARTID = PART.ID 
INNER JOIN WO ON PICKITEM.ORDERID = WO.ID 
INNER JOIN PICK ON PICKITEM.PICKID = PICK.ID 
INNER JOIN UOM ON PICKITEM.UOMID = UOM.ID
LEFT join trackinginfo on trackinginfo.recordid = pickitem.id and trackinginfo.tableid =   -1515431424 and trackinginfo.parttrackingid = 5
left join uomconversion on uomconversion.touomid = (select id from uom where code = 'kg') and   uomconversion.fromuomid = pickitem.uomid
WHERE PICKITEM.STATUSID=30 
AND UOM.ID IN (8,14) 
AND PICKITEM.ORDERTYPEID=30
ORDER BY PICK.NUM, "Quantity Kg", trackinginfo.info
```

Comment: You probably need to do something with a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE), or you could use a loop in a stored procedure or `EXECUTE BLOCK`.

Comment: Can you use stored procedures here?